# How to increment the name attribute array using javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to increment the value of the name attribute whenever the function is called. Below I have added all the code through which I add new text boxes using jQuery clone function. Hope now everything is clear.

```js
 

function addQuestion(){
 var question = jQuery('#question-template').clone();  
 question.css("display","block").removeAttr('id');
 jQuery('#questions').append(question);
}    

function renameQuestions(){
 jQuery('.question-box').each(function(i,v){
  jQuery(this).find('.question_id').html(i);
 });
}

jQuery('#add-question').on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 addQuestion();
 renameQuestions();
});
 
jQuery(document).on('click','.del-question', function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 jQuery(this).closest('.question-box').remove();
 renameQuestions();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="quiz[0][english][ques_title]" class="ques_title" placeholder="Enter question title" value="">
<textarea name="quiz[0][english][ques_desc]" class="ques_desc" rows="4" placeholder="Explaination here...."></textarea>
<a id="add-question" class="button" href="#">Add</a>
<a class="del-question button" href="#" data-id="1">Remove</a>
```

I want to increment the value quiz[0], whenever the add-question button is clicked, I tried using PHP adding a PHP variable in the JS function. But then I got to know it will not work because one is server side and other is client side scripting.

Comment: So, on click, you want the `quiz[0]..`s to all turn into `quiz[1]..`s, is that it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes that's it

Comment: @topper1309 Where's the code for increment? Did you try anything?

Comment: @KK I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/5163/

JS:

```
function renameQuestion() {
    var question = $(".question-box:last");
    var total_question = parseInt((".question-box input:first").attr("name").replace( /^\D+/g, ''))+1;
    question.find("input").each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      elem.attr("name", elem.attr("name").replace(/[0-9]/g, total_question));
    });
  }
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: For this I will have to write the same code for multiple fields right ? Like I have 2 textboxes and 4 radio buttons

Comment: @topper1309 I am not sure. Can you share your full code where you add the new inputs?

Comment: I have added the full code, thank you for responding. I hope I can find a solution for this problem @KK

Comment: I found a problem in this, when I remove one box and then again add one more textbox. Then there is a duplicate array index number, because it counts the total length of ".question-box"

Comment: @topper1309 you could have changed it by yourself. Check the update.